# How to stop loading all images in page loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I developed the one eCommerce site using laravel 7 Now I facing an issue is when I click the category page that time it's loading all product images. I want to stop that.

I have a category called Appereal this category has more than 100 products I wrote a query with a pagination limit of 12 but when checking my bandwidth usage is high because this time it's loading all products when clicking the category page.

I want solutions like when I click the category page I want to load the first page 12 products only after clicking the second page only have to load the other 12 images.

Please help me or advise me on how to fix these issues with laravel.

**My Query**

```
$pro = DB::table('category_and_products')
                ->join('sub_category_one','sub_category_one.id','=','catpro_sub_cat_one')
                ->join('product','prod_product_code','=','catpro_prod_code')
                ->join('supplier','supp_code','=','prod_supplier_code')
                ->select('prod_product_code','prod_supplier_code', 'product_name', 'prod_image1', 'prod_from_price','supp_margin','prod_supp_margin','prod_seo_title')
                ->where('suco_seo_title','=',$mId)
                ->where('supp_flag','=','1')
                ->groupBy('prod_product_code')
                ->orderBy('supp_seq_no','ASC')->orderBy('product_name','ASC')->paginate(12);
```

Comment: Read this: [Pagination in Laravel 7](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination)

Comment: In your blade(front) add a link for pagination: {{ $pro->links() }}

Comment: you can use Model Eloquent relation and using closer you can set a limit on category images. Using join will have cartisan result based on matching columns

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ajax load and manipulate it to work as pagination.
I have used it for my module. You can take reference from below:

```html
<script>
  var ENDPOINT = "{{ url('/') }}";
  var page = 1;
  infinteLoadMore(page);
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
      page++;
      infinteLoadMore(page);
    }
  });
  function infinteLoadMore(page) {
    $.ajax({
      url: ENDPOINT + "/blogs?page=" + page,
      datatype: "html",
      type: "get",
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('.auto-load').show();
      }
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      if (response.length == 0) {
        $('.auto-load').html("We don't have more data to display :(");
        return;
      }
      $('.auto-load').hide();
      $("#data-wrapper").append(response);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      console.log('Server error occured');
    });
  }
</script>
```